# Why does this globally defined css rule affect styling inside of the shadow DOM?

Tags: html, css, web-component, shadow-dom, text-align

I created an web-component with shadow mode 'open', which is used like this:

```
<scu-switch checked="true" value="switch1">
  <span id="scu-switch-label">Switch On</span>
</scu-switch>
```

and looks like this:

[image: Html Toogle Button]

Than I added the button to a webpage with the following global CSS:

```css
  text-align: center;
```

and now the button style is broken:

[image]

When I inspect the button I can see, that the global style was applied to the span (and notice that it is not part of slot content) **inside** of the shadow root.
[image: Developer Tools]

The shadow DOM is supposed to [isolate style](https://css-tricks.com/encapsulating-style-and-structure-with-shadow-dom/) from the rest of the web page.
Why was this `text-align: center` applied here, even though it was defined outside of the Shadow DOM?

Comment: Can you create codepen of above code and share link of the same

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> One of the great features of the Shadow DOM in Web Components is that styles are encapsulated to the component - you can style your component without worrying about any specifier (id, class, etc.) conflicts or styles '**leaking out**' to other elements on the page.

> This often leads to the belief that the reverse is true - that styles outside of the component won't cross the Shadow boundary and '**leak in**' to your component. However this is only partly true.

> While specifiers do not leak in to your component (e.g. a color applied to an p element in a style rule outside of your component won't effect any p elements in your Shadow DOM, although the rule will be applied to your Light DOM, or slotted content),

> ***inheritable styles* applied to any elements containing your component will be applied to both your Shadow and Light DOM.**

**Source:** https://lamplightdev.com/blog/2019/03/26/why-is-my-web-component-inheriting-styles/